# Sql join with sum up duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

1)The sample data set looks like this:

```
create table user(
  user_id int,
  name varchar(10),
  surname varchar(10)
  );


  insert into user(user_id, name, surname) values 
  (1, 'a', 'aa'), 
  (2, 'b', 'bb'), 
  (3, 'c', 'cc');


create table books(
    user_id int,
    book_name varchar(10)
);

insert into books(user_id, book_name) values
(1, 'book1'), 
(1, 'book2'), 
(1, 'book3'), 
(2, 'book1');

create table expanses(
    id int,
    user_id int,
    amount_spent int,
    date timestamp
);

insert into expanses(id, user_id, amount_spent, date)
values
    (1,1,10, '2020-02-03'),
    (2,1,10, '2020-02-03'),
    (3,1,30, '2020-02-02'),
    (4,1,12, '2020-02-01'),
    (5,1,15, '2020-01-31'),
    (6,1,13, '2020-01-15'),
    (7,2,15, '2020-02-01'),
    (8,3,20, '2020-02-01');
```

2)The result which I want:

```
| CountUsers | amount_spent |
|---------|--------------|
| 2       | 77           |
```

Explanation: I want to count

a) how many users have book1 or book2 and

b) how much total they spend on a date between 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03.

Now how the query should look like?

I am using MySQL version 8.

I have tried:

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
     , sum(amount_spend) as total_amount_spend
  FROM
     ( select sum(amount_spend) as amount_spend
         FROM expanses e
         LEFT 
         JOIN books b
           ON b.user_id = e.user_id 
        WHERE (b.book_name ='book1' or b.book_name ='book2') 
          and e.date between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-03' 
        GROUP 
           BY e.user_id) src'
```

And the result is wrong because the select clause from the inside(a little bit modified to show you more clearly):

```sql
select amount_spend as amount_spend
FROM expanses 
LEFT JOIN books ON books.user_id = expanses.user_id WHERE (books.book_name ='book1' or books.book_name ='book2') and expanses.date between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-03'
```

3)Will return something like this:

```
| user_id | amount_spent | book_name |
|---------|--------------|-----------|
| 1       | 10           | book1     |
| 1       | 30           | book1     |
| 1       | 30           | book1     |
| 1       | 12           | book1     |
| 1       | 10           | book2     |
| 1       | 10           | book2     |
| 1       | 30           | book2     |
| 1       | 12           | book2     |
| 2       | 15           | book1     |
```

4)So if sum this up, we will get

```
| CountUsers | amount_spent |
|---------|--------------|
| 2       | 139           |
```

5)Which is wrong, because there are duplicates.

If we add DISTINCT to `sum(DISTINCT amount_spend)`
it will be also wrong because it will give the following result

```
| CountUsers | amount_spent |
|---------|--------------|
| 2       | 67           |
```

To summarize, you can see in table 3) there are some duplicates of amount_spent cause the book_name.(one to many relationships)

How to avoid duplicating amount_spent but stay with book_name?

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2AXqjsaVmpLPjt4XfqXJpP/0)

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042464/sql-left-join-with-sum-up

Comment: A little bit diffrent, look at the fiddle

Comment: Do you know the answer for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(distinct user_id) 
     , sum(amount_spent) 
  from expanses 
 where expanses.date between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-03'
   and user_id in (select user_id from books where book_name in('book1','book2'))
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26ifPWyRRKGp9YVQXg1qje/0

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for a)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) total FROM books WHERE book_name IN ('book1','book2');
```

Here's an idea for b)

```
SELECT SUM(amount_spent) total_spent 
  FROM expanses e
 WHERE e.date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-03'
   AND EXISTS 
   ( SELECT * 
       FROM books b
      WHERE b.user_id = e.user_id
        AND b.book_name IN ('book1','book2')
  );
```

Here's and idea for combining a) and b)

```
SELECT SUM(amount_spent) total_spent
     , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) total FROM books WHERE book_name IN ('book1','book2')) total_customers
  FROM expanses e
 WHERE e.date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-03'
   AND EXISTS 
   ( SELECT * 
       FROM books b
      WHERE b.user_id = e.user_id
        AND b.book_name IN ('book1','book2')
  );
```

Comment: I have added `id` field which is the primary key. Now, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Edited accordingly.